# In Jaspersoft Studio, Sql server procedure returning fewer fields than expected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I running a sql server procedure in Jaspersoft Studio (JSS), but the Query Dialog only show one field.

How it looks in JSS:

[image: Procedure on Jasper Studio - show only one field.]

In the SQL SERVER Management Studio, it works correctly. The procedure returns more than ten fields...

[image: Procedure on SQL SERVER Management Studio]

Has anyone seen a similar case? What might be happening?

I wrote a java code to check, and by jdbc java application, show all fields normally:

```
 Connection conn = VAGASConnectionFactory.getNewConnectionSQLDRIVER(VAGASConnectionFactory.AMBIENTE.DESENV);
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call pr_cria_tabela_relatorio_parametrizado(90918)}");
    ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "," + rs.getString(2) + "," + rs.getString(3) + "," + rs.getString(4));
    }
```

The result of this code runs correctly:

*Jéssica Alba,28/04/1981,35,Condado*

*Jim Carrey,17/01/1962,54,Goiana*

**But in Jasper Studio, only shows one field**.... :-/

The Jasper Studio log when a click to "Read fields":

```
Start ClassPath Mapping
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/55/1/.cp/lib/jasperreports-6.1.1.jar
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/55/1/.cp/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-6.1.1.jar
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/55/1/.cp/lib/jasperreports-fonts-6.1.1.jar
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/55/1/.cp/lib/jasperreports-functions-6.1.1.jar
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/lib/js-common.jar
Mapping: Archive: file:/home/diego.queres/.eclipse/1695504528/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/lib/js-extra-classes.jar
End ClassPath Mapping
```

I'm using Jasper Studio 6.1.1. I tried use Jasper Studio 6.3.0, without success too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a stored procedure from Jasper Report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871642/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-from-jasper-report)

Comment: @AlexK I've tried to use syntax similar to this: `Call procedure_name ($ P {parm1}, $ P {parm2} )`, and had no effect.
I use another stored procedures that work normally. This only happened to this procedure.

This procedure fill a dynamic VARCHAR @SQL (MAX). Which runs at the end with an EXEC command.

I've already tried:
1) Change @sql to varchar (max) - without success
2) Include SET ANSI_WARNINGS, and SET NOCOUNT to OFF - without success

Comment: @AlexK, the problem is not about how to call stored procedure from Jasper Report, because Jasper Studio runs normally with another procedures.

Comment: I tried replace the JDBC driver for another version, but without success - JDBC driver is https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, what I discovered is the Query Editor is limited to read fields if a have a complex stored procedure (like mine). As my procedure uses cursors and dynamically makes a sql query in a string, reading the procedure scheme is hampered by the Query Editor.

I decided do the following: print the query SQL to the procedure output *(print @sql)*. Then I cut and paste the query that runs (on the procedure output) in the Query Editor window *(instead of the procedure call, "exec procedure ....")*. Thus the Query Editor can read the fields of the query. After query editor read fields, **I delete the query SQL and insert the procedure call again, "exec procedure ...."**.

Now it worked :-)