# stored procedure with parameters in jaspersoft studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make a report based on stored procedure base on 3 parameters.

In Query field if I hard cord like.

```
    Exec myStoredProce 1,2,3
```

It will work fine,
If I don't want to hard cord if I want to pass those parameters from somewhere. what should I change in queries?

if I'm using asp.net MVC how can I pass parameters from it to jasper studio or server after publishing?

Comment: Did you try to use parameters?

Comment: Alex, just tell me how to use parameters? and after publishing if I am doing a api call how should I pass those parameters?

Comment: Using parameters: [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871042/876298). Passing parameters from Java: [Fill JasperReport Template using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/3958/fill-report/13819/fill-jasperreport-template-using-java#t=201610141133328210775)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a stored procedure from Jasper Report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871642/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-from-jasper-report)